# What’s the difference between "cannot" and "can’t"?

Tags: formality, modal-verbs, contraction-vs-full-form

Can anyone explain the difference between *cannot* and *can’t* is?

Is the only difference that *cannot* is more formal than *can’t* is?

Comment: When a mother wants to get the point across,she uses a child's full name. "Mary Weatherspoon Smith, you get to bed this minute!" Similarly the full form has more strength than the corresponding contraction. I suspect that everything I have said is true in other languages, and I hope that the lurking linguists will set me straight if I am wrong.

Comment: I'd like to point out that whatever the difference, it's the same difference there is between other pairs of contracted vs uncontracted negations (like *is not* vs *isn't*). The peculiarity with *cannot* is that it's not written as two separate words, but that's really just a spelling detail. However, it's worth noting that *can not* is also valid but normally means something else! "Right now I cannot think" means that I'm presently unable to think; "Right now I can not think" means that I am currently able to avoid thinking (an unusual sentence, but there are more idiomatic examples).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning.

There is a mild difference in use:

- Contractions like *can't* have until recently been strongly deprecated in the most formal writing, and it will usually be avoided in legal/bureaucratic contexts. But the academic dialect (at least in the humanities) is creeping closer to the colloquial style, and using *can't* will not usually be regarded as an error (though your editor may change it).
- By the same token, in ordinary conversation *cannot* will usually impart some air of formality; but the effect is slight, and will probably not be noticed unless it accompanies a general 'rise' in your diction toward the written dialect.

Comment: Sometimes *cannot*  feels more in the deontic mode than *can’t* does, becoming more like *must not* in sense.

Comment: @tchrist mmm ... I'd be inclined to say that deontic *cannot* tends to be somewhat severer than deontic *can't*, and that that's a result of its marked formality.